# How object creation is handled in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am reading this mannings book, where it is mentioned that. You represent your instance methods with #. So in Rails, when you point some route to `'controller#action`. Clearly action is an instance method, But I did not create any object for the controller class, how this has been taken care of?
 Some one told me that, every request creates a new controller object, but I am not sure about it. If that is the case, *there will be too many objects in the RAM I feel*.

Can someone point me to some source on this topic. I could not find them by googling, and there are no similar questions in SO

Comment: This sort of info is all in the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
Work your way through them and you'll understand how controllers and actions work.

Comment: @TarynEast Thanks for the comment. Can you point me to a specific rails guides page, in which I can read upon the topic for the time being.

Comment: I think your misunderstanding of how it works is too broad to be covered in a single page. The guides are not that long considering how much info is packed into them. Start from the beginning and work your way through - it will give you a much better foundation for working with rails. I recommend this to everyone who is a learner of rails (including my students at General Assembly when I taught full-stack Rails dev). Trust me, you'll be better off after you've read them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [action controller guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions)

> When your application receives a request, the routing will determine which controller and action to run, then Rails creates an instance of that controller and runs the method with the same name as the action

Many thousands of objects are allocated for each request. While reducing that is an ongoing area of work, 1 controller instance per request is not a problem.

Comment: Can you tell us when object are deallocate?

Comment: when the garbage collector decides that they can be deallocated